# How can I change color for a single input and change color for 3 inputs differently?

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement, background-color

How can i make For all of the observation color to change except if $ceeeee1view is "Mastered", data is only required to be inputted once before the colour changes and three times if the data is mastered?

```
                          if ($e1view =='good' && $e1view !=',Mastered' && $e1view !='Mastered,Mastered') {
                             $ceeeee1view =$e1view;
                          }
                          elseif ($ee1view =='good' && $ee1view !=',Mastered' && $ee1view !='Mastered,Mastered'){
                             $ceeeee1view =$e1view;
                          }
                          elseif ($eee1view =='good' && $eee1view !=',Mastered' && $eee1view !='Mastered,Mastered'){
                             $ceeeee1view =$e1view;
                          }
                          elseif ($eeee1view =='good' && $eeee1view !=',Mastered' && $eeee1view !='Mastered,Mastered'){
                              $ceeeee1view =$e1view;
                          }
                          elseif ($eeeee1view =='good' && $eeeee1view !=',Mastered' && $eeeee1view !='Mastered,Mastered'$eeeee1view, ",") =='1' ){
                              $ceeeee1view =$e1view;
                          }
                          elseif ($e1view ==',Not Applicable' ){
                              $ceeeee1view = 'Not Applicable';
                          }
                          else {
                               $ceeeee1view = '';
                          }
                    


                    switch ($ceeeee1view) {
                          case "Mastered":
                              $color1="#12c4f9";
                              break;
                          case "good":
                              $color1="#fd0303";
                              break;
                              break;
                          
                          default:                     
                      }
                      /* //////////////////// */
                      ?>
```

Note: If it is mastered, the color should remain until mastered is 3 times.

Comment: Please note that the code and logic are very hard to understand. Just spend more time in refactoring it. Use better variables names, conditions, etc.

Comment: okay, it has been optimized @MihaiMatei

Comment: could you please format your code correctly so it's easier to read?  Please refer to creating a [mcve] for hints on how to improve this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that same logic as your question,
set all observation color to a variable you want then use the if else statement for if `$ceeeee1view` is `"Mastered"` or not, then change to the color you want it to be.